# Loading Excel files to SSIS in foreach loop - data types and field lengths issue

Tags: excel, ssis, oledbconnection, ssis-2012

I read Excel files in a for-each loop via Excel Data Source.
The problem is that SSIS is changing dynamically the type and size of the columns depanding on the first couple of rows in consecutive Excel file.

Let's assume that it's based on the 1st row (I know it's about 8 rows as a default).
In the example below "code" is read as DT_FLOAT, however if the 3rd row was 1st it would have been DT_STR.

id|code
1 |333
2 |14145
3 |aaaavwv

My question is - how to define a **fixed data structure**, which would be used each time a new Excel file is loaded in the loop?
I would like to override the Excel Source with SQL stetement - something like CAST or CONVERT, but I guess it's not allowed here.

SELECT CAST([id] as int) as ID, CAST([code] as VARCHAR(30)) as code
FROM [Sheet1$];

Connection string:
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\SHARE\Data\;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;MODE=READ;READONLY=TRUE;IMEX=1";

What I tried and does not work:
- adding IMEX = 1 to connection string
- setting column lengths in Advanced Editor

Comment: What about a derived column transformation to CAST the problem columns to the desired datatype every time?

Comment: Derived column - yes, it's an option providing that the excel is already loaded The error occurs on Excel Data Source step - very first one in Data Flow process. Thanks for the comment anyway.